# not a valid Android SDK

Tags: livecode

I'm trying to configure Location of Android development SDK root in Livecode 9.6.9 but whatever folder I select I get following error:

"The chosen folder is not a valid Android SDK. Please ensure you have installed it correctly, and enable support for 12 (API 31)"

I've installed latest Android Studio (Flamingo) and downloaded API 31 package and command line tools.

I've installed JDK 8.3 but JDK Path is always (none), don't if can be same problem.

Can you help me configuring it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have api31 installed and the sdk tools installed then the problem may be with the java version, Livecode seems to be very picky about this.

Try java 8.073, this works for me 8.02 did not.
Also if you install multiple versions of java, open the preferences and go to the mobile pane,you can run this code in the message box

```
set the visible of button "ChooseJDK" of group "Android SDK" of card "Mobile Support" of stack "revPreferencesGUI" to true
```

to show a java sdk file picker button so that you can exoeriment with different versions.